# How can I validate a group within another group and maintain separate error messages?

Tags: jquery-validate

I'm trying to use the 'require_from_group_update' method with jquery validator and have run into a snag I need help with.  I working with multiple forms (24 in total) and each has many, many fields.  In some instances, I need to validate groups of questions.  As long as the groups are exclusive, this works great, but in some instances, for example, I need to have 5 total answers but at least 3 from the last 4 questions.

So that could mean 1 question in the first group is required and 4 from the second or 2 from the first and 3 from the second, etc.  In my real form, the forms have between 10 and 20 questions long with different required counts for each.

I created the example with the fields in separate groups but really wanted to see if it was possible to check if 3 of the last 4 questions are answered and that 5 out of the total 8 are also answered.  I tried to have all questions in one group and the last 4 in another - but that didn't work.  Here I just picked 8 as example - in reality, there can be 10 to 20 total questions with varying requirements for each.

Many thanks in advance - I hope this is clear and concise enough.

Sample code is below - or there's a fiddle as well - [jsfiddle.net/43rdworld/qZ6rn/4/](http://jsfiddle.net/43rdworld/qZ6rn/4/)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>Online Nomination Form</title>
            <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" ></script>
            <script src="//ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.0/jquery.validate.js"></script> 
            <style type="text/css" media="all">
      textarea {margin-left:20px;}
      .wrapper {width: 200px;clear:both;float:left;margin-bottom:10px;}
      div.errorContainer {width:200px;float:left;font-size:9pt;}
            </style>     
    <script>
              $(document).ready(function () {
                $("#theForm").validate({
                  groups: {
                    group1: "sm_Appreciation,sm_Impact,sm_Safety,sm_People,sm_Parents,sm_Goals,sm_Money,sm_Decision",
                    group2: "sm_Parents,sm_Goals,sm_Money,sm_Decision"
                 },
                   rules: {
                     sm_Appreciation: {require_from_group_updated: [2, ".smg1"]},
                     sm_Impact: {require_from_group_updated: [2, ".smg1"]},
                     sm_Safety: {require_from_group_updated: [2, ".smg1"]},
                     sm_People: {require_from_group_updated: [2, ".smg1"]},
                     sm_Parents: {require_from_group_updated: [3, ".smg2"]},
                     sm_Goals: {require_from_group_updated: [3, ".smg2"]},
                     sm_Money: {require_from_group_updated: [3, ".smg2"]},
                     sm_Decision: {require_from_group_updated: [3, ".smg2"]},
        },
              errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                 if ((element.attr("name") === "sm_Appreciation") || (element.attr("name") === "sm_Impact") || (element.attr("name") === "sm_Safety") || (element.attr("name") === "sm_People")) {
                            error.appendTo("#smError1");
                    } else if ((element.attr("name") === "sm_Parents") || (element.attr("name") === "sm_Goals") || (element.attr("name") === "sm_Money") || (element.attr("name") === "sm_Decision")) {
                            error.appendTo("#smError2");
                    }
          },
        });

        jQuery.validator.addMethod('require_from_group_updated', function (value, element, options) {
            var numberRequired = options[0];
            var selector = options[1];
            var fields = $(selector, element.form);
            var filled_fields = fields.filter(function () {
            // it's more clear to compare with empty string
                return $(this).val() != "";
            });
            var empty_fields = fields.not(filled_fields);
            // we will mark only first empty field as invalid
            if (filled_fields.length < numberRequired && empty_fields[0] == element) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
            // {0} below is the 0th item in the options field
            }, jQuery.format("* Please fill out at least {0} of these fields."));
        });
    </script>
</head>
    <body>
    <form name="theForm" id="theForm" method="post" action="" autocomplete="off">
        <h4>Answer 5 of the following 8 questions, with at least 3 from questions 4-8</h4>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Appreciation">1. Question 1</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Appreciation" id="sm_Appreciation" class="smg1" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="1"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="smError1" class="errorContainer"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Impact">2. Question 2</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Impact" id="sm_Impact" class="smg1" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="2"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Safety">3. Question 3</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Safety" id="sm_Safety" class="smg1" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="3"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_People">4. Question 4</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_People" id="sm_People" class="smg1" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="4"></textarea>
        </div>
        <h4 style="clear:both;">Answer at least 3 questions from questions 4 through 8</h4>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Parents">5. Question 5</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Parents" id="sm_Parents" class="smg2" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="5"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div id="smError2" class="errorContainer"></div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Goals">6. Question 6</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Goals" id="sm_Goals" class="smg2" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="6"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Money">7. Question 7</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Money" id="sm_Money" class="smg2" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="7"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="wrapper">
            <label for="sm_Decision">8. Question 8</label><br>
            <textarea name="sm_Decision" id="sm_Decision" class="smg2" rows="3" cols="20" maxlength="200" tabindex="8"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both;"><input type="submit" value="submit"></div>
    </form>
</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First I updated the plugin to version 1.11.1 and I included the corresponding version of [the `additional-methods.js` file](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/additional-methods.js).   Version 1.11.1 is where all the bugs were finally fixed in the `require_from_group` method.

Then I simply created a group within a group.  You already have the right idea with your `groups` option, but that's only used for consolidating the error messages.  Since your whole form is one group, you have to apply the `require_from_group` rule to all fields.  Then since you have another unique group within it, you have to again apply the `require_from_group` rule to only those fields.

```
rules: {
    sm_Appreciation: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"]
    },
    sm_Impact: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"]
    },
    sm_Safety: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"]
    },
    sm_People: {
       require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"]
    },
    sm_Parents: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"],
        require_from_group: [3, ".smg2"]
    },
    sm_Goals: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"],
        require_from_group: [3, ".smg2"]
    },
    sm_Money: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"],
        require_from_group: [3, ".smg2"]
    },
    sm_Decision: {
        require_from_group: [5, ".smg1"],
        require_from_group: [3, ".smg2"]
    }
},
```

And finally, you can clean up your `errorPlacement` by using the class name rather than manually checking against each field name.  I also removed the `.appendTo()` method because it just keeps repeating the error message creating a whole string of the same message over and over.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    // if it's only part of 'smg1' group and not 'smg2' sub-group
    if (element.hasClass("smg1") && !element.hasClass("smg2")) {
        $("#smError1").html(error);
    // else if it's part of 'smg2' sub-group
    } else if (element.hasClass("smg2")) {
        $("#smError2").html(error);
    }
},
groups: {
    group1: "sm_Appreciation,sm_Impact,sm_Safety,sm_People",
    group2: "sm_Parents,sm_Goals,sm_Money,sm_Decision"
}
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/2xW76/**

You'll probably still need to tweak your message placement and your `groups` option for the exact desired effect, however, my demo shows the working logic for validation of groups within groups.

Comment: Thanks so much - that's just what I needed.  One odd thing I noticed that I'll have to look into - and it may just be me - using  require_from _group did not play well with the other fields on my form. Anything upstream of the grouped fields was ignored - i.e.  didn't validate or gain focus. Changing back to the require_from_group_updated allowed all the fields to get validated.  As I said, something to look into.  Thanks again.

Comment: @43rdworld, that's the bug!  You **must use the latest version** (1.11.1) of the plugin and additional-methods files.